# How to draw some graph without using data and function? (turtle analog)

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, turtle-graphics

Is there any method to make a graph like following picture? In Gnuplot, have any command like "lineTo , moveTo , arc, ... etc"?
If I want to produce some picture like this
[image: turtle graphics]

What I should do for producing this picture?
in turtle graphics, just need some codes

```
repeat 36 [rt 10 repeat 2 [fd 100 rt 90]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do similar things with gnuplot. Of course, gnuplot needs to know the coordinates of the lines' start and end points, so you somehow have to calculate them. Something like the code below: you write the coordinates into a datablock and plot it `with vectors`, also check `help vectors`. Graph created with gnuplot 5.2.8.

**Code:**

```
### vector plot similar to turtle graphics
reset session
set size square 
set angle degrees

x0 = 0
y0 = 0
a0 = 0
r0 = 10
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:36] {
        a0 = a0 - 10
        do for [j=1:2] {
            print sprintf("%g %g %g %g",x0,y0,x0=x0+r0*cos(a0),y0=y0+r0*sin(a0))
            a0 = a0 - 90
        }
    }
set print

plot $Data u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) w vectors nohead notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

By the way: couldn't this turtle graphic command actually be simplified to?

```
repeat 36 [fd 100 rt 110]
```

Yes, as @Friedrich shows, it can be done without datablock.
Here is a modified version of my first shot without modulo `%`. The fifth column, i.e. `(x0=x0+r*cos(a),y0=y0+r*sin(a),a=a-110)` is not used for plotting, but just for calculation.

**Code:**

```
### vector plot similar to turtle graphics
reset session

set size square 
set angle degrees
set xrange[-2:12]
set yrange[-10:4]
r = 10
set samples 36
plot a=x0=y0=0 '+' u (x0):(y0):(r*cos(a)):(r*sin(a)): \
                (x0=x0+r*cos(a),y0=y0+r*sin(a),a=a-110) w vec nohead not
### end of code
```

**Result:** (similar to graph above)

Comment: glad to hear. If this answers your question, please check the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A short solution using polar coordinates:

I just noticed a nice behaviour of combing `polar` mode and the special filename `'+'`. Along with the updated solution of @theozh using `vec`, it simplifies to

```
set size square 
set angle degrees
set polar

pl a=0, [i=1:36:1] '+' us (a=a+110):(1):(100):(0) w vec nohead
```

Thus, the turtle snippet can be translated almost directly.
[image]

Even a bit shorter, the same plot can be done with

```
set sample 36
pl '+' us ($0*10):(1):(100):(0) w vec nohead
```

Comment: Probably the shortest way to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version similar to @theozh without datablock

```
set size square 
set angle degrees

r = 10
pl a=x=y=0, [i=1:2*36+1:1] '+' us (a=a-int(i)%2*10-90, x=x+r*cos(a)) : (y=y+r*sin(a)) w l t ""
```

`int(i)%2` emulates a second loop counter for an alternating subtraction of 10.

[image]